# Python unusual import issue

Tags: python-3.x, docker, python-requests

I have written a script that queries ElasticSearch for events, parses the results and updates a status page.

The script is to be deployed in a docker container in our stacks. I have choosen one of the official python docker images for the task: **python:3.6.5-stretch**

Everything worked fine until I dockerized the script. Now, I have a very quirky behaviour regarding the import of python-requests

If I execute the script I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                    
  File "/monitops.py", line 4, in <module>
    import requests   
ImportError: No module named requests
```

My shebang and relevant import:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import elasticsearch                                                                                                                                                                                                   
import requests
```

Now, if I drop to any python shell, it doesn't matter if python, python3 or usr/bin/env python3, I can import requests just fine:

```
root@f37fedb9b7b4:/# python
Python 3.6.5 (default, May  5 2018, 03:05:30)
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
>>>

root@f37fedb9b7b4:/# python3
Python 3.6.5 (default, May  5 2018, 03:05:30)
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
>>>

root@f37fedb9b7b4:/# /usr/bin/env python3
Python 3.6.5 (default, May  5 2018, 03:05:30)
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
>>>
```

Furthermore python and python3 are symlinks of the same executable, python3.6:

```
root@f37fedb9b7b4:/# which python
/usr/local/bin/python
root@f37fedb9b7b4:/# ls -l /usr/local/bin/python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root staff 7 May  5 03:06 /usr/local/bin/python -> python3
root@f37fedb9b7b4:/# which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
root@f37fedb9b7b4:/# ls -l /usr/local/bin/python3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root staff 9 May  5 03:06 /usr/local/bin/python3 -> python3.6
root@f37fedb9b7b4:/# ls -l /usr/local/bin/python3.6
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root staff 33024 May  5 03:05 /usr/local/bin/python3.6
```

The only way the script runs without complaining for the import is being invoked by /usr/local/bin/python

```
/usr/local/bin/python myscript.py

[ The script runs like expected ]
```

I would really like to know why this happened, I have found a workaround, but need to understand this behaviour

EDIT:

I run the script from a crontab, which I create in the entrypoint:

```
#!/bin/bash  

export ES_ENDPOINT

if [[ -z $ES_ENDPOINT || -z $CRONTAB_OPTS ]]; then
    echo -e "\nThe required variables are not set!\n"
    exit 2
fi

echo -e "${CRONTAB_OPTS} python3 /monitops.py >> /var/log/cron \n" | crontab - 

touch /var/log/cron

service cron restart

tail -f /var/log/cron
```

I have tried running the crontab with python, python3 and executing it, I have tried a system cron in /etc/cron.d and the issue persists.

In my Dockerfile I install requests and elasticsearch with pip:

```
RUN pip install requests elasticsearch
```

Comment: Just a little side note, if you are dealing with symlink-cascades like yours or in an alternatives-environment, use `readlink -f $(which python)` to find the actual location of the executable.

Comment: How are you running the script `/monitops.py` exactly? This could be useful to know, e.g. if your Dockerfile creates a non-root user, or if the entrypoint does something special.

Comment: I have updated the question with the entrypoint and relevant info.